# How to make temporary/one time use link in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-router

Im making serverless app. Using React + NodeJS + Firebase Functions. I want to make temporary/one time use link for "reset password" page. How I can do this?

Comment: which database are you using for your application?

Comment: Firestore by Firebase Google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will try to explain shortly, feel free to ask for explanation.

1. In node js you can generate a token and save it in firestore or any db
   you are using
2. In react make a route with a token as route param and accept in it with react hooks inside the component of that route and send it to the backend for verification with the password as a form data (with a post request)
3. Once verified/changed the password, remove the token from your firestore or db you are using.
   I hope in that way, you can get a temporary reset password link.

or follow this tutorial for detailed explanation: [This Link](https://medium.com/@terrychayes/adding-password-reset-functionality-to-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-4681480195d4)

Comment: @ArturSalikhov My pleasure :)